# Anyone able to get lightbox2 working in a react site?

Tags: reactjs, lightbox2

I am able to get it working on my Gatsby site when using `gatsby develop` locally and it works incredibly! But sadly it always causes my build to fail when trying to deploy to Netlify. I could really use some help if anyone has any experience getting non-react packages to work in a react environment. Or if anyone has recommendations of alternative lightbox packages that were made to work with react. Either way, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fslightbox-react seems good. Otherwise I would need more context (error messages and stuff) to help you.

Comment: Here is what it shows in my Netlify Deploy Log...
https://i.imgur.com/NeE8jzD.png

Does that help?